# Android Studio does not download from website

Tags: android, android-studio

I've tried numerous times to Download Android Studio over the last few days from the site [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) but it simply does not do anything, it just says the file has started downloading and then goes straight to the install page without doing anything. I reached out to them on Twitter and they gave me a link, to download it but the link never loads when I click to download it. Any ideas? I have a video of the exact issue I can email to you if you think you know how to amend it. If someone could help me out I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-2-2 use this link to download installer of Android Studio V2.2.2.

Comment: Do you access the internet via a proxy or an application firewall?

Comment: May be any firewall causing this. Because google could servers are so strong and stable.

Comment: I used the link you supplied and the same happened, loaded for a long time and nothing happened, i'm not using a proxy and i've disabled firewall now. Still nothing, any other tips?

Comment: October 2023, using Chrome on Windows, I found that the uBlock Origin extension was preventing the Terms and Conditions popup from appearing when I pressed the button to download Android Studio.  I disabled the extension and restarted Chrome and then the download worked.

Answer (score 4):

I also got the same problem, but when I choose "English" on the language selection, then download button worked.

Comment: Just saved my time. THX!

Comment: Thanks, had to toggle between languages a couple of times then it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the same problem. I had to download it from the archive, which includes the latest version.

Goto https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

Pick the version and then pick the installer for your o/s.

Answer (score 0):

Use below official link for Android Studio download

https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Comment: That's the link i've been using, doesn't work for me

Comment: Hi Lally may be Android developer site block by your firewall or any other proxy setting in your pc please unblock this website because this site also need you for android development help.

Comment: check you have a enough space in your system or try another web browser for downloading . my suggestion use chrome.

Comment: I tried Chrome, Edge and Firefox. All the same result

Answer (score 0):

The website cares strongly about what browser you are using.  I don't trust google at all and i think it was specifically designed to break in Edge and IE.  It uses metadata provided by the browser to determine what version to offer to you, and it's had problems in the past because of it.  Javascript also needs to work properly in your browser and it may even require cookies.  Javascript definitely though.  If you have the problem again, try a different browser.  I've had to switch browsers before because Chrome quit working on my banking site.